# "Золотая лихорадка": как правильно писать?

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать "Золотая лихорадка": нужны ли кавычки и где тут большие буквы?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ни кавычки, ни заглавные буквы здесь не нужны. Золотая лихорадка уже давно стала самостоятельным фразеологизмом, непрямое значение слов которых, выделять вовсе не нужно.